# Why flex-grow in the first div affects the third div?

Tags: css, flexbox, flex-grow

My understanding about the `flex-grow` property is that the elements extend to take the space and this taken space is determined by the value of this property.

So if we have a flex container that has 3 child divs, the first one has `flex-grow: 1`, the second `flex-grow:2`, the third with `flex-grow: 3`, now we have 6 pieces so the third would take 50% of the space.

Why did adding a flex-grow value to the first div affect the third one?

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cont>div {
  margin: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}

.cont>div:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  flex-grow: 5;
}

.cont>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.cont>div:nth-of-type(3) {
  /* flex-grow:1; */
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u4e2psh3/

When I added `flex-grow: 5` to the first div i expected that it will take up the most of space of the parent container but I was confused when found that the third one was the one which was extended.

So why did the first one not extend but the third one did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "first" div in the fiddle is being selected using "nth-last-of-type" rather than "nth-of-type", so the styles are being applied to the last div instead.

Comment: Good catch thanks, this got me crazy, seems the auto complete of editor!!